# keypress event blocking all keyboard keys

Tags: jquery, keypress, jquery-events

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        filtruj();
        return false;
    }
    return false;
});
```

I want to call `filtruj()` whenever the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and prevent a page submit.

Normally this function is called with click on `<a href="#" id="filterButton" onclick="filtruj();" class="t-button t-grid-add">Filtruj</a>` element.

What is happening instead is that I am unable to type anywhere in the form fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the last `return false`, you are preventing all keys being from being input.

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        filtruj();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Trivial answer. Deleting mine since you beat me to it by seconds ;)

Answer (score 3):

Remove the last `return false;`

It will result in a `e.preventDefault()`, which btw should be enough in your first case as well.

`return false;` will also result in `e.stopPropagation()`, which you dont need.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/): "jQuery normalizes the `.which` property so you can reliably use it to retrieve the character code".